# Send E-mail notification If a certain value (IP Address) is found in the array

Tags: c#, if-statement, console, email

I have a C# console application and want to be able to send an Email to a certain address if any IP addresses that are not local are found in the array, I am assuming I would use a If != statement but i cannot get anything to work. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    System.Net.IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(C);
   {
     string IPs = "";
     bool firstIP = true;
     foreach (IPAddress ip in addresslist)
         {
            if (!firstIP)
                {
                   IPs = IPs + ",";

                }
                    IPs = IPs + ip;
                    firstIP = false;
                   }
                     addresslist.ToString();
      if addresslist != { "10.1.20.99"} //example, have multiple IP's
       then //..... this is where I am stuck
```

Comment: Btw, you can use `String.Join` to replace the whole loop: `IPs = String.Join(",", addresslist.Select(ip => ip.ToString()))`

Answer (score 1):

you can remove local addresses with

```
var filteredIPs =  ipaddresslist.Where(p => !p.StartsWith("10.1"));
```

Then you can send a message with something like `sendimportantmails(String.Join(",", filteredIPs));`

Comment: The Starts with part seems to not be working on my app, also I do not want to remove these local addresses from the array, i just want an email to be sent IF any non-local IP addresses are found.

Comment: Its not removing it from the array, its making a list without local IPs in it.. StartsWith should be working -  in what way isnt it working?

Comment: okay cool, and it says "IPaddress does not contain a definition for 'StartsWith' and no extension method 'StartsWIth' accepting a first argument of type 'IP Address' could be found ( are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Comment: no but it is part of string... so that should work. maybe p.ToString().StartsWith( ..)

Comment: When I do that..;. it gives me Exceptions: ArgumentNullException, no Overload for method 'StartsWith' takes 4 arguments.

Comment: no there wouldnt but then nor would that code give you that. error as theres only 1 string in it

Comment: Well that is what it is giving me.. I am not sure what you are trying to say?

Comment: The code i gave you didnt have 4 parameters, suggesting you typed it wrong

Comment: yeah i figured it out, the problem was you assumed i was just using that one IP address to check against I had to use a || Statement and separate it out i was trying to make the list from 4 different local IP addresses.

Comment: No, I didnt assume that atll, hence mine says filterIPs (which will be an array or list) and to run sendimportantmails with a string.join implying more than !

Comment: If you still feel theres a problem post your code here, cos by shortening to startswith you only need to enter the early part of your IPs it sounds more like you've changed the code to add more IPs to the starts with..

Comment: I've got the var working with the startswith I am just now trying to figure out how to send an email out if any IP's not on the startswith list becomes registered

Comment: var filteredIPs = addresslist.Where(p => !(p.ToString().StartsWith("10.1.") || (p.ToString().StartsWith("10.11.") || p.ToString().StartsWith("10.22.") /*|| p.ToString().StartsWith("92.53.")*/)));
            if(filteredIPs != null)
                      {
                             foreach (IPAddress filteredIP in filteredIPs)
                                     {
                                          Console.WriteLine(filteredIP.ToString())                         }
  sendimportantmails(String.Join(",", filteredIPs));
                                                            }

Comment: Well, 10 will always be internal so instead of day lots of 10.xx you could have just do startswith 10. 92 isnt really internal, but if you need to exclude it your list of filteredip should just contain items not matching that.. So whats the issue now?

Comment: No issue, just trying to send an email to a certain email address if anything but the starts with list comes up

Comment: So you're fixed and sorted?

Comment: Yes, there were certain credentials I just needed to send emails throughout the enterprise from a console app, got them and everything is figured out. Thanks for your help.